# ASP.Net Web API - Extract header in common place

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on SaaS application where I have implemented ASP.Net Web API as a service layer. In my Web API, when any request generated, it will have one header value "x-companyid" which is company specific and identify request comes from which company (Tenant).

I require that companyID in all my ApiControllers in Web API project. Of course I can get header value in every ApiController by using "Request.Headers.GetValues("x-companyid") but it will be repeated in all ApiControllers.

I have tried to create "BaseApiController" and inherit all my ApiControllers from "BaseApiController" but it's not allowing me to override ActionExecuting so that I can extract header at common place.

Can anyone suggest how can I extract "x-companyid" header commonly in my project so that I don't have to repeat code in all ApiController?

Comment: Use Custom action Filters. as they intercept each api call for specific
Controlls.

Comment: @IbraHim M. Nada - I can use custom "ActionFilter" at ApiController level but say for ex. I extracted header and stored inside variable, how can access this common variable in ApiController?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: if my answer help kindly mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Your Best friend are action filters.
as they intercept each api call for specific controllers.

All u had to do is to decorate the controler name with something u made like

```
[Tenant]
public foo MyController()
{}
```

this approach gives you controll over what controllers you wish to add this extract to happen becouse maybe youll need some lookup apis and stuff that dont need to be for a specific Tenant

here is a very Helpful link :

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/filters-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5-0-part-twelve/

**Update**

since there is a only one company for each instance 
i would recommend adding a singleton for the current tenant u can access that anyway

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: @ IbraHim M. Nada - I understand your approach but my question is after extracting "x-companyid" header inside "ActionFilter" and assume I stored into "companyID"  variable, how can I access that "companyID" variable inside "action methods" inside "ApiController" ?

Comment: using a singleton all of the current companyInfo stored in it
aka: static class has a virbale called companyId 
u can pass this class anywere.
this approach  called a singleton